# Magento: Add dynamic code to head section in specific CMS Page

Tags: html, magento, php

I'm trying for a while now to get some code into the head section of our custom 'contacts' CMS page. The plan is to make this page to a configurable popup window through a backend setting (true/false).

So far I managed to rewrite the *app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/**Head.php***.

The problem is that any changes made to this file occur on all pages wich wouldn't make to much sense for a popup window.

Any ideas how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the Layout Update XML field of your CMS page:

```
 <default>
     <reference name="head">
         <block type="core/template" name="headerInsert" template="yourthemepath/headerInsert.phtml"/>
     </reference>
 </default>
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine. Thanks alot!
Though the close tag </block> is unnnecessary here since you closed it inline -> <block "stuff" />.

Comment: True, that closing block can go! Please tick as accepted answer if this answer solves your problem.

Comment: Sry forgot it. There you go. Rep. for you :)